# access class members from main

Tags: java, swing, swingbuilder

i'm working with swing builder in java, the form:
[image: swing builder image]
but I can't access the components from main:
[image: code image]
how can I get access to the form components?

Comment: welcome. please don't post image of your code when posting, if it's necessary the add code too.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it

```
public class firstSwingForm {
private JPanel config;
private JTextField startTxt;
private JTextField dogTextField;
private JPanel mainPanel;
private JTextField a5TextField;
private JButton startBtn;
private static firstSwingForm instance;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("App");
    instance = new firstSwingForm();
    frame.setContentPane(instance.mainPanel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    instance.startBtn.setText("text can be set");
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `private JButton startBtn` needs to be declared static in order to be accessed within the main method: `private static JButton startBtn;`

You should also instantiate it as a new object within the main before calling anything on it: `startBtn = new JButton(...);`

It's also worth noting, by convention, your class name should be `FirstSwingForm`,
and think through whether or not those instance variables will be used elsewhere or if they can be defined within main.